# About Wordpress capabilities

Tags: users, content, cms

I know WordPress is best for blog engine and with some plugin like Advance Custom Field, WP can become a great CMS. But it still good for publisher to push content to user. Now I have quite a situation. My friend want to use WP as a engine where user can contribute their post and others can review it. Is it possible to do with WP

I can create a custom theme & plugin to do the trick, but is it good for performance when user put a lot of things (pages and post) on it?

Answer (score 2):

> ...use WP as a engine where user can contribute their post and others can review it.

I don't think you need a plugin for what you want to do.

Enable user registration on your WordPress site by going to **WordPress Dashboard > Settings > General** and checking **Anyone can register** option.

Then right below it is the **New User Default Role** setting which has a drop-down menu next to it that allows you to set the "role" for newly registered users. Set it to **Contributor**.

Now like you said, the "Administrator(s)" and/or "Editor(s)" of the WordPress site can approve/disapprove/publish/delete the posts made by the "Contributors". Contributors themselves cannot publish their posts.

Read this for [more info on User Roles in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

**NOTE:** Assigning the role of a "contributor" to all registered users may not be such a great idea. So, instead you can set the New User Default Role to "Subscriber" and manually promote user(s) to the role of a "Contributor". That's just an idea. You can do it in a way that suits you best (like email requests for example).

Comment: You should probably manually add contributors rather than allowing anyone to register as a contributor. Or at least have some intermittent step where you delay access until an admin has allowed a registration.

Comment: agree, we should not grant permission like that